# ColdFusion 9: nested implicit struct issue

Tags: coldfusion

I'm running into a strange issue when I try to use quoted key values in nested implicit structs.

```
<cfset outer = {
    inner = {
        standard = "works",
        "quoted" = "does not work"
    }
} />
<cfdump var=#outer.inner["quoted"]# />
```

This produces the error: `Element quoted is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.`

Dumping the entire `outer` struct shows no value there as well.

What's going on here?

Comment: 9.0.0 had a bunch of bugs. 9.0.1 is absolutely essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me.  Are you on ColdFusion 9.0.1?  I believe there were some bug fixes related to nested structs/arrays in 9.0.1.  Try installing the updater if you have not.

Comment: It looks like it's running 9.0.0. Since I can't update at this point, I'm going to assume you're correct. Thank you.

Comment: There are more than just bug fixes in 9.0.1 there are some potentially serious security issues that were fixed in later updates so be sure to install the 9.0.1 (or 9.0.2 if you don't need Verity) updater as soon as you can as well as all the relevant hot fixes.

Comment: Here's the readme: http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/release-note/coldfusion-9-0-update-1.html